# Create a graph with clickable nodes [Networkx]

Tags: python, networkx, interactive

I am developing a small example with a network.

I use Networdx to create the graph. For example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%pylab inline
    G=nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3])
    G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3)])
    G.nodes()
    nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

I am searching for examples/documentation because I need to do some extra things on the graph.

My actual graph is big, and I do not want to show only the label of the node, but also some extra information of each node.

For example, I am searching for examples/documentation of how I can make a node clickable in a way that when I am clicking on the node more information is shown next to it.

Also is it possible to define the width of the edge between the nodes?

What I have looked already is the documentation of Networkx:http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/networkx-1.11/reference/drawing.html

Comment: I don't know what your third condition means, and you should probably revise your question so that it's a clear question rather than a request for examples.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am trying to make it more clear. Any feedback is useful

Comment: What is the environment and backend here? `%pylab` suggests `ipython` or something building on `ipython`.

Comment: I am working in notebook jupyter using Python 2